# Paths to exclude when caching WorkPress blog with Akamai

Tags: wordpress, akamai

I'm integrating a WordPress blog website with Akamai, while not sure what paths to exclude.

The following paths have been suggested, while are there any others, for example the preview urls.

```
wp\-.*\.php
wp\-admin
```

Please suggest a sample of Akamai configuration. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does your site use property manager?  If so, under the Property Management Configuration section there is a "Wordpress Admin" template you can include which will give you what you're looking for.

Let me know if this doesn't solve your problem, but it's a frequently asked question so we created the template to make it easy to set up.

Thanks!
Kirsten
API Evangelist, Akamai

Comment: This feature is cool! I will work with our Ops guys to try it out!

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you better select which paths to include instead.

Else, you would need 100% surgical control on busting the cache for every possible reference your page uses. For example, if you have a folder with javascript files, CSS files or images, you truly need to have control on when those files' cached version must expire, or you will start having all kind of issues. Even some redirects will be cached (specially with IE v9-11, which caches redirects due a bug).

It's much easier to define which assets you will truly need to be cached and control when the cache must expire.

Comment: Will try with the "Wordpress Admin" template that Kirsten has suggested. But your comments is also useful though, will keep that in mind while implement it.